# Get PID of running firefox process

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

How can get I get the PID of the "firefox" process in C?

In this code, `system` only returns 0, indicating success. How can I get the PID?

```
int x = system("pidof -s firefox");
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Comment: Well, no, 706989 is about Python, not C.

Comment: Use [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) instead of `system`.

Comment: I've reworded your question to make it easier to read; but I'm just a person like you, so if you disagree, you can change it back.

Comment: The `system()` command returns a value related to the given command's exit status.  You want the command's *output*.

Comment: All I want function that Return pid  to caller

Answer (score 1):

`popen` is what you want: it opens a process and output from the open process is available to read just like a file stream opened with `fopen`:

```
FILE *f = popen("pgrep firefox", "r");
if (NULL == f)
{
    perror("popen");
}
else
{   
    char buffer[128];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, f))
    {
         // do something with read line
         int pid;
         sscanf(buffer, "%d", &pid)
    }
    // close the process
    pclose(f);
}
```

See [man popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)